# How to know if a process is a parent or a child

Tags: c, linux, unix, pid, systems-programming

How does one identify if a process is a child/grandchild of another process using its `pid`?

Comment: [`man 2 getpid`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/getpid)

Comment: `ps -eal | less` inspect the columns `PID` and `PPID` (and `man ps` as well ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Process IDs: Child- and parent processes

All running programs have a unique process ID. The
[process ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier), a
non-negative integer, is the only identifier of a process that is
*always* unique. But, process IDs are reused.

As a process terminates its ID becomes available for reuse.  Certain
systems delay reuse so that newly created processes are not confused
with old ones.

Certain IDs are "reserved" in the sense that they are being used by
system processes, such as the *scheduler* process. Another example is
the *init* process that always occupies PID 1. Depending on the system
the ID might be actively reserved.

Running the commands

```
> ps -eaf | head -n 5
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 11:49 ?        00:00:02 /sbin/init splash
root         2     0  0 11:49 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
root         3     2  0 11:49 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         5     2  0 11:49 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:0H]
```

and

```
> pidof init
1
```

will allow you to independently verify this.<sup>1</sup>

In C we can use the following functions to get the process ID of the
calling process and the parent process ID of the calling process,

```
#include <unistd.h>

pid_t getpid(void);
pid_t getppid(void);
```

A process can create other processes. The created processes are called
"*child processes*" and we refer to the process that created them as
the "*parent process*".

## Creating a new process using fork()

To create a child process we use the system call
[`fork()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)

```
#include <unistd.h>

pid_t fork(void);
```

The function is called once, by the parent process, but it returns
twice. The return value in the child process is 0, and the return
value in the parent process is the process ID of the new child.<sup>1</sup>

A process can have multiple child processes but there is no system
call for a process to get the process IDs of all of its children, so
the parent observes the return value of the child process and can use
these identifiers to manage them.

A process can only have a single parent process, which is always
obtainable by calling `getppid`.

The child is a *copy* of the parent, it gets a *copy* of the parent's
data space, heap and stack. They do *not share* these portions of
memory! <sup>2</sup>

We will compile and execute the following code snippet to see how
this works,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

int main(void) {
    int var = 42; // This variable is created on the stack
    pid_t pid;

    // Two processes are created here
    //                 v~~~~~~~~~~|
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        perror("Fork failed");
    } else if (pid == 0) { // <- Both processes continue executing here
        // This variable gets copied
        var++; 

        printf("This is the child process:\n"
               "\t my pid=%d\n"
               "\t parent pid=%d\n"
               "\t var=%d\n", getpid(), getppid(), var);

    } else {
        printf("This is the parent process:\n"
               "\t my pid=%d\n"
               "\t child pid=%d\n"
               "\t var=%d\n", getpid(), pid, var);

    }


    return 0;
}
```

We will see when we execute the program that there are no guarantees
as to which process gets to execute first. They may even operate
simultaneously, effectively interleaving their output. <sup>3</sup>

```
$ # Standard compilation
$ gcc -std=c99 -Wall fork_example1.c -o fork_example1
$ # Sometimes the child executes in its entirety first
$ ./fork_example1
This is the child process:
     my pid=26485
     parent pid=26484
     var=43
This is the parent process:
     my pid=26484
     child pid=26485
     var=42
$ # and sometimes the parent executes in its entirety first
$ ./fork_example1
This is the parent process:
     my pid=26461
     child pid=26462
     var=42
This is the child process:
     my pid=26462
     parent pid=26461
     var=43
$ # At times the two might interleave
$ ./fork_example1
This is the parent process:
     my pid=26455
This is the child process:
     my pid=26456
     parent pid=26455
     var=43
     child pid=26456
     var=42
```

---

<sup>1</sup> **PID** stands for *Process ID* and **PPID** stands for
*Parent Process ID*.

<sup>2</sup> The process ID 0 is reserved for use by the kernel, so
it is not possible for 0 to be the process ID of a child.

<sup>3</sup> Many systems do not perform a complete copy of these
memory segments and instead only creates a copy when either process
performs a write. Initially, the shared regions are marked by the
kernel as "read-only" and whenever a process tries to modify these
regions the kernel awards each process their own copy of that memory.

<sup>4</sup> Standard out is *buffered* so it's not a perfect example.

Comment: It's easy to know which process is the child when these are your processes, but I think the question is about determining this about pids of other processes.

Comment: And I believe your second example actually tells you if you are in the main thread of a process, not if you are in the main process (whatever that means).

Answer (score 2):

Use getpid() and getppid() function to get process id and parent process id.